# Can I block creation of new Nether Portals in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In vanilla Minecraft, is it possible to block creation of new Nether portals? This is for a Survival/Adventure hybrid map; I want the player to have a great deal of freedom, but to control access to the Nether to portals I've placed in the world.  I can ask players to not build new portals, but it would be nice to have the rule mechanically enforced.

Possibilities include: somehow detecting and destroying the Nether portal blocks when they appear; not allowing the portal to be activated in the first place, and damaging the obsidian frame; somehow "tainting" any obsidian in the world or created so it's no longer eligible to be part of a port.

I'm at a loss for what a solution might look like beyond "Probably some command blocks." Trying to /testforblock every block in the world seems impractical.

Comment: Crazy thought, but how about making the Nether totally destroyed so someone cannot build anything in it? Like, flooding everywhere with lava, spawn a ton of Zombie Pigmen, etc.

Comment: This should definitely be doable, but it will take some command-block-fu.

Comment: That's not a bad fallback plan, although since I do want to use the Nether in controlled ways, the player could open a portal and end up in the area that does exist. If you mean fill it with, say, lava, then clear it for the "correct" portal, also intriguing...

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `/fill` command to replace nether portal blocks with air. You don't want this running all of the time though, only when a player uses flint and steel. First, create an objective to track when flint and steel is used:

```
/scoreboard objectives add usedFaS stat.useItem.minecraft.flint_and_steel
```

Then, run these two commands on a clock in this order to clear nether portals around the player who just used a flint and steel:

```
/execute @a[score_usedFaS_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /fill ~-6 ~-6 ~-6 ~6 ~6 ~6 air 0 replace portal
/scoreboard players set @a[score_usedFaS_min=1] usedFaS 0
```

Note that this will replace any portals nearby, so you should have something to relight the portals that you want to stay lit.

Comment: There are other ways to light a nether portal...

Comment: @MBraedley True, forgot about that. Obsidian can also be created indirectly, so I don't think it'd be completely and practically possible (without something like keeping coords/entities at where every proper portal should be) to detect and remove player-made portals.

Comment: That's my idea, and come to think of it, you could set a up a marker armor stand atop each valid portal, and then `execute` a scoreboard update for players within range of it.

Comment: @MBraedley Should work, might also need to also set the score for enderpearls.

Comment: Make sure the selector is `@a[score_usedFaS_min=1,name=!username]` so that the asker can place their portal without it being destroyed. Another option is `@a[score_usedFaS_min=1,m=!1]` so that anyone in Creative Mode can make a portal without its destruction.

Answer (score 0):

Removing flint and steel or obsidian from the inventory would require a simple /clear command like the following

> /clear @a flint_and_steel
>   /clear @a obsidian
>   /clear @a fire_charge

Comment: Not a valid answer: portals can be casted in-place, and there are other ways to light a portal (lava, for instance)